# Запуск python скрипта на удалённом сервере в фоновом режиме

Tags: python, python-3.x, paramiko

Есть сервер_А, есть несколько других серверов (host_1, host_2, host_3). Необходимо запустить с сервер_А скрипт который пройдёт по всем другим серверам и запустит скрипт в фоне с параметрами,так чтобы не ждать возврата данных с каждого хоста.

```
from paramiko import SSHClient, AutoAddPolicy


def get_cmd_out(cmd, host, ssh_log, ssh_key):
    with SSHClient() as ssh:
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(host, username=ssh_log, key_filename=ssh_key)
        _,stdout, __ =ssh.exec_command(cmd)
        result = stdout.read()
        out = result.decode('866')
    return out

ssh_log = 'tester'
ssh_key = '/some/key.pub'
hosts = ['host_1','host_2','host_3']

python_venv = '/path/to/venv/bin/python3'
script_path = '/path/to/script.py'
params = '--some params'
cmd = f'{python_venv} {script_path} {params}'

for host in hosts:
    result = get_cmd_out(cmd, host, ssh_log, ssh_key)
```

Как правильно написать `cmd` чтобы оно не ждало возвращения вывода команды с каждого хоста, а передало в работу и пошло передавать команду следующему хосту?

Comment: Для вашей задачи можно попробовать использовать [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from paramiko import SSHClient, AutoAddPolicy


def get_cmd_start(cmd, host, ssh_log, ssh_key):
    ssh = SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(host, username=ssh_log, key_filename=ssh_key)
    return ssh, ssh.exec_command(cmd)
    
def get_cmd_out(ssh, stdin,stdout,stderr):
    result = stdout.read()
    out = result.decode('866')
    ssh.close()
    return out

ssh_log = 'tester'
ssh_key = '/some/key.pub'
hosts = ['host_1','host_2','host_3']

python_venv = '/path/to/venv/bin/python3'
script_path = '/path/to/script.py'
params = '--some params'
cmd = f'{python_venv} {script_path} {params}'

connections = []

for host in hosts:
    ssh, pipes = get_cmd_start(cmd, host, ssh_log, ssh_key)
    connections.append([ssh, *pipes ])

for con in connections:
    out = get_cmd_out(*con)
```

Разбить функцию на две. Сначала стартуешь на всех хостах - потом забираешь результат

Comment: отличный вариант, спасибо